# jquery: how to append elements to empty object

Tags: jquery

I want to create a set of options, that will be appended to every select in grid column

```
<option> option 1 </option>
<option> option 2 </option>
...
<option> option N </option>
```

but I don't know how to create a set of elements without parent element.

appending to an empty jquery object doesn't work

```
var options = $('');
options.append('<option></option>')
```

Comment: How many selects are we talking about here? You might be better off making a select with the nested options and changing name/id/class as needed. Appending 40 items under a parent has much better performance than appending 40 items.

Comment: we are talking about "40 selects" ).  I need just options because user can select another source for options, and all select should be updated on the page

Comment: Are there other options in the selects than what you are adding?

Comment: yes, and options are different (class, name, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Select = $("body").append("<select><option>...</select>");
//if you don't want that select, remove it. But it could feasibly be your first select added to the page
Select = $("body").remove(Select);
var Options = Select.find("option");
```

Per you comment you might want to use the

```
$('select.selectClass').replaceWith(Select);
```

This will allow you to stick with a parent element.

Comment: +1: I deleted my answer since I ended up modifying mine to suit your suggestion.

Comment: :) I was about to comment on the difference between .html() and .append() and the questions disappeared...

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga append is a += html is just =. i.e. html will overwrite existing content.

Comment: I meant to ask the other angle of it, I mean will .html() also create the dom for it automatically ?If I write .html("some html"), will it create DOM elements in the "some html" part? Thanks

Comment: for that matter will .append() or .html() create the dom elements of the passed in strings (if the string has some html tags in it)?

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga correct. append does the same when passed a string.